# Which file contains Environment-Variable of a JUnit-Project?

Tags: junit

I have a Maven-Project in Eclipse with JUnit4 for Testing. It works well, but I have a question:

In Run Configuration for JUnit is there the tab "Environment" with a lot of variables.
Where are saved these variables? In which path/file can I find/write them?
Or, would be posible to copy-paste all these variables, instead to write manualy each one in this tab?

Thanks for your help, Chris

Answer (score 0):

founded! these are saved not in project-files. they are in
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches\